# PHP remember last search phrases

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have seen many sites doing that. You can see search phrases under the search field. Which is the best way to implement that?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to show recent searches of the current user or show the most popular searches?

Comment: Do you mean recent search phrases per user or something like autocomplete with recommended/often searched phrases from all users together?

Comment: Something like most popular searches.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with autocomplete.

Comment: I want to show recent searches, not only for the current user.

Comment: Well, you just need to log search terms in a separate table, and retrieve it via Ajax when the user selects the search box. You need to have a go at writing it yourself and come back with any problems you have.

Comment: it reminds me of a case during acceptance phase, one employee typed something like "stupid boss" and guess who was trying the search at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the most recent searches, just save those searches anywhere. In your database for example (or even a plain text file would work). Create a table `recent_searches` and save the latest queries in there. Use a cronjob to clear the table once in a while (if you want). When performing a search, you can insert it into your recent_searches table, for example:

```
$searchterm = 'Apple Pie Recipe';
// Insert the search into your recent search table
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `recent_searches` (`term`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($searchterm) . "'");
// Then search.
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `searchtable` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($searchterm) . "%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

To retain the search fields after page gets reloaded,
You are querying the database based on search fields

```
$mysearchStr =$_POST['searchPattern'];
if(empty($mysearchStr)
{
echo'<input type="text" name="searchPattern" value="">';
}
else
{
echo'<input type="text" name="searchPattern" value="$mysearchStr">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution will vary a bit depending on how advanced you want to do this. If you only want to show the most popular searches, then I guess you can just have on table in your db and save the complete search term in one column, and have a second column where you do +1 every time someone search for that exact term. If the search term isn't already in your table, you add it.

That is a bit limited however. If you want to to be able to show trends for instance, or if you want to show most popular searches today, I guess a better way would be to use two db-tables. Your first table stores an id and the complete search term. Your second table store one row for every search, and contain an ID of the search term used, and a time-stamp for when the search was done.

Using the second alternative would give you a whole lot of more possibilities, as you know the date and time of every search done one your site.